# Is it safe/bad practice to create shared pointers from a weak pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, circular-dependency, weak-ptr

## Introduction

I have two classes I call `Node` and `Point` here. Points are objects which hold specific information (which information exactly does not matter I use a simple integer in the example). Nodes are objects which manage several points if they should share the same information. So `Node` has a list of pointers to all the points it manages (which is fine because `Point`removes its reference from the node if its lifetime ends) and each point has a back reference to the node itself. This creates a circular reference which makes things a bit tricky. I do not use multithreading, so races of any kind are not a concern. Also I am bound to use C++03 (so C++98, basically) and boost 1.53 so there is a limitaion in features I can use.

EDIT:

as it seems to be a bit unclear i wanted to add that this is really a very minimalistic extraction of the actual code. As i wanted to provide a minimal working example i tried my best to extract the functionality from the original program. However be sure that using shared pointers is necessary in the actual program since these resources are shared across several objects with different classes. Also i use shared pointers because they are always optional which means you can check them for NULL and act differently if they are not assigned as can also be seen in the code below.

## The problem

I have not yet described the "back reference to the node" any further because this is where the problem begins. So at the moment I settled with this solution:

My `Node` contains a weak pointer to itself so the ownership can be shared to other points. On adding a point, the node creates a shared pointer from the weak pointer like this

```
p->node = this->weakThis.lock();
```

but I do not know if this is just bad practice or contains serious problems which I do not see since the reference to [weak_ptr::lock()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock) only states that it creates a new shared object despite its confusing name, or if this is acceptable code.

## Other solutions I have thought of

- All classes get shared pointers

  - good: No need to create shared objects from weak ones
  - bad: The shared object inside the class needed to be explicitely deleted (like with a call of a method for example `Node::destroySelfReference()` which can easily be forgotten. Otherwise the object could live forever with a reference to itself.
- All classes get weak pointers

  - good: we just need to copy the weak pointer and not share ownership
  - bad: everytime we wanted to access the node from the point we needed to call `lock()`. And since the reference in `Point` is not really used as observer but is used like a shared reference this is obsolete.

## Question

What would be the best solution here? And which are the real dangers of them?

## Code

```
/* Using boost 1.53 */
#include <vector>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/weak_ptr.hpp>

using boost::shared_ptr;
using boost::make_shared;
using boost::weak_ptr;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

/*-------------Classes-----------*/

class Point;

class Node {
private:
    std::vector<Point *> points;
    weak_ptr<Node> weakThis;
public:
    int value;
    Node(Point * p, shared_ptr<Node> & sp);
    void add(Point * p);
    void remove(Point * p);
    int getValue() {
        return this->value;
    }
};

class Point {
private:
    int value;
public:
    shared_ptr<Node> node;
    Point() : value(2) {}
    ~Point() {
        if(this->node != NULL) {
            this->node->remove(this);
        }
    }
    int getValue() {
        if (this->node == NULL) return this->value;
        else {
            return this->node->getValue();
        }
    }
};

/*----------Node definition------------*/

Node::Node(Point * p, shared_ptr<Node> & sp) : value(1) {
    sp.reset(this);
    this->weakThis = sp;
    this->add(p);
}

void Node::add(Point * p) {
    this->points.push_back(p); /* simplified without checking if element exists since it is unnecessary for the problem */
    p->node = this->weakThis.lock(); /* <- critical part */
}

void Node::remove(Point * p) {
    std::vector<Point *>::iterator it = std::find(this->points.begin(), this->points.end(), p);
    if (it != this->points.end()) {
        Point * pr = *it;
        this->points.erase(it);
        pr->node.reset();
    }
}

/*------------main-----------*/

int main() {
    Point p;
    cout << "Value of unmanaged p is " << p.getValue() << endl;
    shared_ptr<Node> n;
    new Node(&p, n); /* This is a bit strange too but other creations will not work */
    cout << "Added p to n" << endl;
    cout << "Value of managed p is " << p.getValue() << endl;

    n->remove(&p);
    n.reset();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you just need `std::enable_shared_from_this` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this

Comment: @Slava which is C++11 and also it seems like boost 1.53 does not support it either

Comment: @Slava okay apparently boost 1.53 supports this sorry. I will look into it thank you very much.

Comment: Circular dependencies are exactly what weak pointers are for. However, I don't see why you need a pointer of any kind back to the node. The node controls the life time of the points it contains, so isn't it guarenteed to exist if a point exists? Why not just pass a reference to the node to each point it creates, if you really need it? I don't see anything in your write up that explains why you are choosing to use shared pointers. Are these objects truly shared? who owns them? what is their lifetime? Make sure this isn't a case of "I use shared pointers cause I want to make everything use them"

Comment: Have you considered not using the heap at all? Your listing would probably be alot faster, and I don't really see a need for the heap here, but not sure what the context is.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz hey thanks for your comment. It may seem like that because i wanted to provide a minimal example and so i tried to isolate the functionality as best as i could but in the actual code the points are contained by other objects but managed by the node so that the other objects just can use the points' values without further checking and also the nodes are kept in a forth object.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz i edited the Introduction so it is clear that i need to use shared pointers

Comment: @Slava i tried a bit around now but i can not figure out how to use enable_shared_from_this properly. Does my Node class still need a shared pointer to itself? Because if i just remove the shared pointer from `Node` and assign the back reference of the point like this `p->node = shared_from_this();` it throws a `bad_weak_ptr` exception.

Comment: **a)** Several `Node` objects store pointers to `Point` objects. Each `Node` can delete these pointers. Same `Point` pointer can be stored in different `Node` objects. Then use `shared_ptr` to store those pointers, being them in `Node` or other types that can delete the `Point` object. **b)** Only an object (`Node` or whatever) can delete a `Point` object. Then store `unique_ptr` in that `Node`. **And**, no matter a) or b), the rest of pointers should be `weak_ptr`, for example the reference in `Point` to a `Node`.

Comment: @Ripi2 **a)** Each node is unique and holds only those points which should have the same shared value. I have to use raw pointers for the points because all smart pointers would destroy the points if i remove them from the class since there are no other shared pointers to them (they are kept in lists as raw objects) and so i can not create a weak_ptr also **b)** i can not use unique pointers since of i destroyed a point the node would be destroyed even if there are several other points which refer to it. And for the last: So it is okay if i call the `lock()` function everytime?

Comment: @Yastanub: You may find [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE) by Herb Sutter interesting. It discusses various trade-offs when implementing a graph data structure using `shared_ptr`'s

Comment: @user786653 ill give it a look when i am home thanks :)

Comment: I don't understand. Who can delete points? If the same pointer can be deleted from several objects then use `shared_ptr` in all of those "points-deletion-capable" objects.

Comment: @Ripi2 "And, no matter a) or b), the rest of pointers should be weak_ptr" weak_ptr does not work with unique_ptr

Comment: @Slava THX for the correction. I write quicker than I think ;)

Comment: @Ripi2 sry it is difficult to understand: Nodes can not delete points thats why i have a destructor for `Point` which removes itself if it belongs to a node. There is a class lets call it `PointCollector` which holds a list of `Point` objects. For this  class it should not be relevant if the point belongs to a node but it should just call `Point::getValue()`. If now the `PointCollector` decides to delete its point the reference in the node should be deleted. There is a fourth class `IMakeThingsDifficult` which needs to know if a point is a node and access the node in that case from the point.

Comment: @Yastanub what I don't understand, why don't you take the approach with `n = make_shared<Node>()` and `p.setNode(n)` and `p.setNode(nullptr)`, and the Point then does the `n.points.push_back(p)` or the remove. The logic behind your code is that if a Point as a Node it reads the value of that or otherwise uses its own. The list in the Node looks more like a helper structure. If you want to keep it even less coupled, you would make `connect_point_with_node(p, n)` and  `disconnect_point_from_node(p, n)`

Comment: @t.niese Because in my original code the `Node` has some other values which are necessary when creating the node which depend on the first point which is added to the node. So i can not provide a default constructor for empty object. I am sorry if those things are cleary missing from my example but including all necessary dependencies would be way too broad so i decided to narrow my problem to what i have provided and these solutions are pretty much what i am stuck with.

Comment: @Slava I think i can not use the `enable_shared_from`_this approach either because i need to call it in the constructor of `Node` where the shared pointer, which is necessary for `shared_from_this()`, does not exist yet.

Comment: @Yastanub But then I would probably more expect to have: `p.setNode`, `p.setNewNode`, and `p.setNewNode` does `make_shared<Node>(this)`, and returns the created newly created `shared_ptr` or a  `connect_point_with_new_node`.